# Laravel 4 - Unable to override getDateFormat()

Tags: laravel-4, overriding

Can anyone tell me why I get an error saying Trailing Data, whenever I Override this method in my model and alter it in any way?

```
protected function getDateFormat() {
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
}
```

Any change to the above code breaks my page.

I am following the official documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps

Comment: What are you overriding it with?

Comment: Right now the exact same code, because nothing else works. return 'Y'; breaks the page, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the same but I would get this error when working with timestamps and carbon but using strtotime() on the data i was passing resolved my issue, may help you.

Answer (score 4):

`getDateFormat` is purely meant for how date/time fields are stored in the database. You're not meant to modify it for display purposes.

EDIT: Here are some suggestions for custom formatting of your datetime fields if you don't want to call `format()` everywhere.

- Make a presenter class
- Add accessor methods like `getDateYearAttribute` and `getDateMonthAttribute`
- Use Carbon's `setToStringFormat` method as documented [here](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-formatting)
- Add a [HTML macro](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros) for formatting dates
- Add a blade extension for the same thing

Comment: What then do I modify to change the displayed format? I'm not interested in the standard output.

Comment: Added some suggestions to the main reply.

Comment: carbons toString isn't even called when using toArray or toJson so its useless